# ffmpeg combine two commands compress and watermark

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I am trying to compress and also add water mark on video via `ffmpeg` each command work great

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -s 480x320 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 1 -ar 16000 -r 13 -ab 32000 -aspect 3:2 output.mp4
```

And:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "hflip[flipped];[flipped]overlay=x=20:y=20" -strict -2 out.mp4
```

But I want to do both command together, What I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -s 480x320 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 1 -ar 16000 -r 13 -ab 32000 -aspect 3:2 && -i logo.png -filter_complex "hflip[flipped];[flipped]overlay=x=20:y=20" -strict -2 output.mp4
```

I used `&&` and `|` or `,` but none of these working as expected, any solution?

> Order is important, It should first compress video then add water
>   mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` can be used to chain together commands to execute the second command if the first one succeeded. You could just take both commands as they were and put `&&` between them:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 \
    -s 480x320 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 1 -ar 16000 -r 13 -ab 32000 -aspect 3:2 output.mp4 \
&& ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "hflip[flipped];[flipped]overlay=x=20:y=20" \
    -strict -2 out.mp4
```

But ffmpeg should support doing both steps with a single invocation (I didn't test this):

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i logo.png \
    -filter_complex "hflip[flipped];[flipped]overlay=x=20:y=20" \
    -s 480x320 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 1 -ar 16000 -r 13 -ab 32000 -aspect 3:2 \
    -strict -2 out.mp4
```